# Conditionally populate a new column

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
[C1]  [C2]  [C3]  [C4]
  a1    b1    c1  val1    -- group 1
  a1    b1    c1  val2    -- group 1
  a1    b1    c1  val3    -- group 1

  a2    b2    c2  val1    -- group 2
  a2    b2    c2  val2    -- group 2

  a3    b3    c3  val1    -- group 3
  a3    b3    c3  val2    -- group 3
```

I would like to generate values for a new column `[c5]`, for each combination of `[c1]`, `[c2]` and `[c3]`. The desired output would be something like:

```
[C1]  [C2]  [C3]  [C4]  [c5]
  a1    b1    c1  val1     1
  a1    b1    c1  val2     2
  a1    b1    c1  val3     3

  a2    b2    c2  val1     1
  a2    b2    c2  val2     2

  a3    b3    c3  val1     1
  a3    b3    c3  val2     2
```

For each group of `[c1]`, `[c2]` and `[c3]`, it will always be the same. You can consider the combination of the 3 columns as the primary key.

Comment: You want this just for the select or you want for the insert command ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I need to create another column and update the new column.

Comment: I see. Then the phrasing was kind of misleading. Do not use the term "auto-increment", which suggests you want the value be automatically generated on insertion.

Comment: I don't think you need a separate column. Read up on CASE - I believe the output you want is achievable with it, not with pre-populating a new column. Additionally, as @Roblll says below, more easily done outside of MySQL - with PHP for instance. Good luck.

Comment: @user3741598 look at my answer. its very simple in MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will take two queries. first query you need to alter the table to add the new column... I just made these varchar as thats what it looks like on my side...

**SETUP:**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(c1 VARCHAR(55) 
,c2 VARCHAR(55)
,c3 VARCHAR(55)
,c4 VARCHAR(55)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
  ('a1'  ,  'b1' ,   'c1',  'val1'),
  ('a1'  ,  'b1' ,   'c1',  'val2'),
  ('a1'  ,  'b1' ,   'c1',  'val3'),

  ('a2'  ,  'b2' ,   'c2',  'val1'),
  ('a2'  ,  'b2' ,   'c2',  'val2'),

  ('a3'  ,  'b3' ,   'c3',  'val1'),
  ('a3'  ,  'b3' ,   'c3',  'val2');
```

**FIRST QUERY:**

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    ADD COLUMN c5 VARCHAR(55);
```

here we just added a new column.. called it c5.

**SECOND QUERY:**

```
UPDATE my_table mt,
(
    SELECT 
        c4, 
        c1, 
        IF(@A = c1, @B := @B + 1, @B := 1) AS new_col, 
        @A := c1 
    FROM my_table
    CROSS JOIN(SELECT @A := '', @B := 1)t
) temp 
SET mt.c5 = new_col 
    WHERE mt.c4 = temp.c4 
    AND mt.c1 = temp.c1;
```

here we do some calculations to do a count that increments for each type and resets when it reaches a new one. then update the table in the same query

**THIRD QUERY:**

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

just a way to see the changes done.

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01fa1/1)

**OUTPUT:**

```
+---+---+---+-------+--+
|c1 |c2 |c3 |c4     |c5|
+---+---+---+-------+--+
|a1 |b1 |c1 |val1   |1 |
|a1 |b1 |c1 |val2   |2 |
|a1 |b1 |c1 |val3   |3 |

|a2 |b2 |c2 |val1   |1 |
|a2 |b2 |c2 |val2   |2 |

|a3 |b3 |c3 |val1   |1 |
|a3 |b3 |c3 |val2   |2 |
+---+---+---+-------+--+
```

**BONUS:**

just for fun you could also just run the query if you didn't want to make a new column in the table. like so:

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4, new_col as c5 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        IF(@A = c1, @B := @B + 1, @B := 1) AS new_col, 
        @A := c1 
    FROM my_table
    CROSS JOIN(SELECT @A := '', @B := 1)t
) as _outer_
```

Comment: On your bonus piece, I have a question on the `cross join`. I tried to remove it and it produced the same output. Is there a reason to do cross join if I just want to select?

Comment: @Boxuan yes there is. the reason why you want to do that cross join is if you dont do it the results will become incorrect. try running it twice without the cross join... basically it makes the variables empty for each time you run it.

Comment: I think every time `@A` is reset to the new value in `[c1]` (`@A := c1`) and then `@B` is reset to either `1` or `@B + 1` based on the condition of `@A`. Am I wrong? I have also tried to run it using your example and my data, commenting out `cross join` works as good. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Boxuan @A is set to the value of the previous row. so before I set it to the value of the next row i check to see if they are the same.. if they are then @B gets incremented.. or else they are different so its now reset back to 1 :)